# What is the difference between the two following structures?

Tags: conditionals, plain-tex, strings

`First`:

```
\def\cs#1#2{00\fi\def\csa{#1}\def\csb{#2}
\ifx\csa\csb}
\if\cs{...}{...}
```

`Second`:

```
\def\cs#1#2{\fi\def\csa{#1}\def\csb{#2}
\ifx\csa\csb}
\if\cs{...}{...}
```

I mean what role does `00` play in this structure?

This is my sample:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\def\a{\fcolorbox{red}{green!20}{true}}
\def\b{\fcolorbox{green}{red!20}{false}}
\def\MadadString#1#2{00\fi\def\sh{#1}\def\sha{#2}
\ifx\sh\sha}
\if\MadadString{Shajarian}{Shajarian}
\a\else\b\fi\qquad
\if\MadadString{tt}{\makeindex}
\a\else\b\fi\qquad
\def\b{\fcolorbox{green}{red!20}{false}}
\def\MadadString#1#2{\fi\def\sh{#1}\def\sha{#2}
\ifx\sh\sha}
\if\MadadString{Shajarian}{Shajarian}
\a\else\b\fi\qquad
\if\MadadString{tt}{\makeindex}
\a\else\b\fi
\end{document}
```

Thanks. My output is:
[image]

Comment: You should not use `\a` or `\b` as macro names. Perhaps you should use `\newcommand`, to see whether the macro name you want to use is already taken by something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no real difference. When `\if` is not skipped, in the first case you get

```
\if00\fi\def\csa{...}\def\csb{...}\ifx\csa\csb
```

In the second case you get

```
\if\fi\def\csa{...}\def\csb{...}\ifx\csa\csb
```

and the `\if\fi` is replaced internally by `\if\relax\relax\fi`. It's less good programming style making TeX add these tokens, so the first method (with `00`) should be used.

Note that `00` can be any pair of unexpandable tokens, equal or not.

Comment: Which one is the less good programming style, the one with the `00` or without? [Perhaps it's a bad sign that it's not immediately clear… :-)]

Comment: @ShreevatsaR The latter is bad programming.